# After Dissolve data Need elevation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, dissolve

I have a problem in Arcmap 9.3 When we are using 3D data in ArcMap to dissolve it the elevations are lost.

Is there someway to keep the elevation during the dissolve method?

Comment: What geometry do you have? Points, lines, polygons?

Comment: Are your [Environment settings configured to maintain Z values](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Output%20has%20Z%20Values)?

Comment: Facing same issue, Any solution?